# Google sheets can't identify a duplicate for a pasted link

Tags: google-sheets

in order to check if there are duplicate copy+pasted links in a column, I have this formula:

```
=if(counta(unique(A:A))<>counta(A:A), "Yes, there is a duplicate", "No duplicate")
```

It works fine for everything except copy+pasted links. When it comes to links, it doesn't count the first duplicate. so if I have as an example,if I pasted

"http://techinfo.honda.com/rjanisis/pubs/OM/AH/A2A154DOM/enu/A2A154DOM.pdf"

in column A twice, it doesn't register. It only works when I have a triplicate, then it senses that there's another duplicate in the column (when in fact, now there's 3 of the same link).

Any workaround? Is this an intended function..? I'm guessing this has something to do with the `=unique()` formula not registering the duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

Extremely odd. I can't see it being intentional. I suspect more to do with updating than `unique`. A possible (but if so very ugly indeed) workaround seems to be to force a "Yes, there is a duplicate" response (say `z` in two cells in ColumnA) before removing the two `z`s and relying on the formula's veracity.